# Failed to update database because it is read-only

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have set up my website to use ASP.NET Membership. it all works fine when trying to use it on my development machine but when I put it on the web server and try to log in, I get this error :

```
"Failed to update database "C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF" because the database is read-only. "
```

Comment: Is the file readonly? Does the asp user account have permissions to write to the directory the database is in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

thanks for the help. I just found a solution. in the App_Data ACL, I had two entries : Network Service and IIS_IUSRS. the Network Service account had full permissions but IIS_IUSRS group had only read access. so, I gave IIS_IUSRS full permissions as well and it worked !

thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to restart the IIS with "iisreset.exe" after altering the permissions

Comment: This was really helpful, the changed permissions were only applied when IIS was restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Check that file on the disk.  Right click and go to properties.

If it is a read-only file, you will need to make it writeable.

Comment: yes, the file is read-only.it inherits this behavior from its parent folder App_folder. funny thing is that when I try to unset the App_Data folder from read-only, it goes back to read-only. don't know what to do ...

Comment: I had a similar problem didn't notice that TFS set it to read-only after a checkin.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is read-only and you can't seem to change it using the Properties window, you have to use a command prompt.

[Refer to this Support article at Microsoft.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549)

Answer (score 1):

The user account that the website is running under needs write permissions on the file.

It is also likely that the file is read-only as result of the transfer and needs to be set to be writeable.

Comment: I gave full permission to the Network Service account. I'm using Windows  7

Comment: Can you post the connection string?

Comment: Hi Oded, thanks for the help. I just found a solution. in the App_Data ACL, I had two entries : Network Service and IIS_IUSRS. the Network Service account had full permissions but IIS_IUSRS group had only read access. so, I gave IIS_IUSRS full permissions as well and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

I followed Attilah's answer and found:
1. Both IIS-ISUR, WebService had full pomission to the App_Data and the mdf.
2. But someone called "asp.net 4.0 pool" and "all users" did not, so I allowed them.

Then 
3. I followed user1280392's answer to run "iisreset" but failed (but still run it pls).

Then I went to IIS manager and did this:
4. Clicked the server's name, clicked "restart" on the right.
5. Clicked the applications name, clicked "restart" on the right.

and it was ok.