# Failed to update database becase the database is read only

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2012, localdb

I have created a winform application and programmatically trying to attach the database when an application runs first time. Unfortunately in windows 7 i always got an error. Please view the screenshot below it tells the whole story. Now my question is that how can i get rid from this error, is there any way to automatically give required rights on the folder where the application installs?. I want to permanently resolve this error and need smooth attachment. Anyone please help.

Please view the error below. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabaseName SET READ_WRITE`

More informations here [on This forum](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=90910)

**Edit**
[This was asked by someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027788/localdb-readonly-database-problems)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is different I have  a read write problem on folder where the application installed. Ur solution works after the problem but what I need is to overcome this issue before it occurred. I mean whenever application installs it already have read write permissions on that particular folder where application installed, so that I will never face this issue, thanks.

Comment: I have a Sql server 2012 LocalDB. When i run alter query it runs for a long time and never give result. How to run alter in LocalDB ?

Comment: alter database [C:\PROJECT POS\PROJECTPOS\BIN\DEBUG\DATABASE\UNIVERSAL_DATA.MDF] set read_write...... When i run this query, it give this error now:- User does not have permission to alter database 'C:\PROJECT POS\PROJECTPOS\BIN\DEBUG\DATABASE\UNIVERSAL_DATA', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.

Comment: I can see this database in sql server management studio with dark gray (read only) image, thanks

Comment: Are you logged in as Admin? (Studio and App). And have you tried the solution of the link I added to my answer?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Iam not logging from any user its open for everyone but I Done it manualy by right clicking on the folder and give full control to everyone group. But my question is still there that during installation how can I programatically set  read write permissions to folder so that the end user will never face the above screenshot error?. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: **[Look at the link I addet to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027788/localdb-readonly-database-problems)**. Here a sample `icacls mydabase*.* /grant "MYMACHINENAME\Administrator":(F)`. *[What is icacls?](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753525(v=ws.10).aspx)*. This should help.

Comment: Thanks for reply and sorry for long previous comments... Now two questions arise: 1-Where to write this code? 2-How to implement at the moment when installation completes?, Thanks.

Comment: This is no code. You call it with an execute command. `Icacls.exe ...`. I don't know what you are using to install your software, but it should support calling an executable.

Comment: I try to execute command on sql server but it not works. Iam going to mark as answer and opening a new thread. I actually needed a VB or c# code to solve this issue. So i will take in a new thread. Anyways thanks for your each comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your database in your own subdirectory of the directory returned by `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` then the user will have read/write access to it.

See [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine if a different location would be more suitable, e.g. `ApplicationData` if you need it to roam or `CommonApplicationData` if you need all users of the computer to use it.

Edit: I found a slightly more extensive version of this answer: [Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files if I Target Multiple OS Versions?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx), please also see the articles it links to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have understanding about these special folders. But do you think that putting application database in these folders is best option other than application folder where an app installs?

Comment: @user3004110 Yes. It will make it work and follows Microsoft's guidelines for where to store data. The application folder should be read-only (for a general user) to hinder malware.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, iam near to conclusion but please tell me one thing more. When I install application the database files are also placed in application folder where I have another folder name database. Now my question is what should I do to move this database folder to special folder? Should I programatically move from application folder to special folder when an application runs first time? Or there is another better way?

Comment: @user3004110 Start here: [VS Setup project: install files in different directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499301/vs-setup-project-install-files-in-different-directories). Any further questions about it would probably warrant a new question if your searching Google etc. doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is somehow late, but I believe people always face the same problems so my case is worth to be shared.

**tl;dr** = Change the permission of deployed files **manually** or using **icacls** command.

Actually I use [*InstallForge*](http://installforge.net/) for packing and deploying my application(s).
No matter what setup creator is used, when the application is installed to a non-system folder ( e.g. D:\ ) the program works perfectly and the database is readable/writable.

Whereas when the application is installed in [Program Files] folder or [Program Files (X86)] folder, Windows takes a preventive security measurement and sets file permission to be only [Read] and [Read & Execute].

I think Windows Vista and later versions of Windows have this behavior.

You can check that by **right-clicking** the installed file and going to **properties** then **Security** tab.

The files I installed on D:\ had **Full-Control** permission while, as I mentioned, the ones on C:\ had only **Read & Execute** permissions.

You won't notice the difference when you install a normal program on C:\ because you might not be writing data on a file or a database. But in case of database deployment, the file has to be writable.

Finally, the solution for this case was telling *InstallForge* to change file permissions at the end of the installation using icacls commands :

```
icacls "C:\MyApp\MyDB.mdf" /Grant Everyone:F
icacls "C:\MyApp\MyDB_log.ldf" /Grant Everyone:F
```

In my case, it is okay to give everyone full-control on the database files, but you might need a customized solution for your case so please refer to :
http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

You can tell your setup creator to run those commands, or you can put them together in a batch file and run it after the installation.